# How to use PHP's sprintf with type specifier %u in C#

Tags: c#, php, c#-4.0

I've searched on StackOverflow and found that PHP's `sprintf` in C# is `String.Format`.

In `sprintf` when the type specifier is `u`, it means the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as an unsigned decimal number.

How do I convert the PHP function `sprintf` with type specifier `%u` to C#?

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
var myInt = -13458;
if(myint >= 0)
    Console.Print(String.Format("This is value threated as %u: {0}", myInt));
else
    Console.Print(String.Format("This is value threated as %u: {0}", -1 * myInt));
```

Reason:

> 1) An optional sign specifier that forces a sign (- or +) to be used on a number. By default, only the - sign is used on a number if it's negative. 
>   [PHP: sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)

Simply multiply it with `(-1)` when input value is less than zero

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for the c# equivalent of sprintf with type specifier u? Are you telling me that String.Format will automatically convert it to a unsigned decimal number. I'm asking this as you are checking if myint >0, if you check here-http://php.net/sprintf , u will find that sprintf with %u works with both positive as well as negative numbers

Comment: Oh, my mystake. I've corrected my answer, I hope it'll help you.